# global scss in Gatsby

Tags: gatsby

I just started using gatsby.

In my normal react-project, I generally have a `common.scss` file. This file contains classes name which I may use frequently

For example

```
.row {
    display: flex
   flex-direction: row
}
```

In React app, I will just import it in the `index.js`. I could just import it in all the files inside my screen folder but I was thinking if there is any better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In gatsby you can create a file **gatsby-browser.js** in the root where you can import styles that you want to be global.

There you can put something like this to import the style

```
import 'pathtoyourcssfile.css';
```

More details can be found here:

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/global-css/#adding-global-styles-without-a-layout-component