# In a Gatsby site with SCSS how do I import local fonts?

Tags: sass, fonts, gatsby

Noob to Gatsby and SCSS I wanted to dive into both and learn them beginning of the new year. After following the [Gatsby tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/tutorial/) I wanted to dive in and build a site based off the [gatsby-starter](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world).

Followed the documentation for [install & config for SASS](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/styling/sass/).

In `src` created a directory named `fonts` and added Open Sans:

```sh
src/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
src/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf
src/fonts/OpenSans-Italic.ttf
```

created a directory in `src` for SCSS called `main.scss` and created a partial directory to bring in typography:

```sh
src/styles/main.scss
src/styles/partials/_typography.scss
```

*main.scss:*

```css
@import 'partials/typography';

body {
  font-family: $font-primary;
}
```

*_typography.scss:*

```css
$font-primary: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

// Body Font:
@font-face {
  font-family: $font-primary;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url('../../fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

In *index.js* I bring in the SCSS with no issues:

```js
import React from 'react'
import '../styles/main.scss'

const Home = () => {
  return <div>Hello world!</div>
}

export default Home
```

but in the terminal I get font errors for each font:

> Can't resolve '../../fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf' in '/path/to/project/src/styles'
>
> If you're trying to use a package make sure that '../../fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf' is installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is correct.
> error Generating development JavaScript bundle failed

Per research I dont see an answer and I've read:

- [global scss in Gatsby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62260913/global-scss-in-gatsby)
- [Using Local Fonts](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/styling/using-local-fonts/)

*gatsby-config.js:*

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [`gatsby-plugin-sass`],
}
```

**Why am I getting an error when trying to bring in local fonts for this site?** Also, I'm bringing in the local font because I read in the documentation there is an offline ability.

---

Edit:

Forked Gatsby with the Hello World Starter:

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]

Comment: Thanks for the sandbox. I've updated the answer fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mindset and your approach is perfectly valid and the issue relies on the relativity of the paths in your `_typography.scss`. Use something like this:

```
$font-primary: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

// Body Font:
@font-face {
  font-family: $font-primary;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url('../fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Notice the error prompted:

> Can't resolve '../../fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf' in
> '/path/to/project/src/styles'

`/path/to/project/src/styles` it's weird, it seems that you have something hardcoded somewhere because of the `/path/to/project/` part. Give it a look too.

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]

The issue relies on your path, which is relative to the `main.scss` file, not to the partial since, in the end, the partial belongs to the `main.scss` file because you are importing it directly.

Comment: ah I see, the docs were not clear about the path but I also assume this means that any developed partial relying on some source would also need the path based on the `main.scss` path because it is the default for combining all the partials.

Comment: If you are combining partials through `main.scss`, yes. If you are importing partials between each other, it's not needed since you are pointing to a specific file